# Sentence segmentation with annotated corpus

Tags: opennlp, corpus, named-entity-recognition

I have a custom annotated corpus, in OpenNLP format. Ex:

```
<START:Person> John <END> went to <START:Location> London <END>. He visited <START:Organisation> ACME Co <END> in the afternoon.
```

What I need is to segment sentences from this corpus. But it won't always work as expected due to the annotations.

How can I do it without losing the entity annotations?

I am using OpenNLP.

Comment: Seems like `<END>` denotes end of the sentence?

Comment: Not really. It denotes the end of an **entity span**.

Comment: I see. Why don't you use the sentence segmenter of OpenNLP?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create multiple NLP models for OpenNLP you need multiple formats to train them:

- [The tokenizer requires a training format](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer.training.tool)
- [The sentence detector requires a training format](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.training.tool)
- [The name finder requires a training format](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.tool)

Therefore, you need to manage these different annotation layers in some way.

I created an annotation tool and a Maven plugin which help you doing this, have a look [here](https://git.noc.fh-aachen.de/marc.schreiber/Towards-Effective-NLP-Application-Development). All information can be stored in a single file and the Maven plugin will generate the NLP models for you.

Let me know if you have an further questions.

Comment: I actually managed to figure out how to do this, I converted the format into standoff format, and then use NLTK's sentence segmenter which allowed me to use the sentence span positions to re-include the entity tags, I will post the script later. But your project seems really good, I will definetly check it out!

Comment: Thanks, I'm always open for suggestions. :-)

Comment: @arop, did you have some time to checkout my project? I now supports to annotate named entities.